# How to get wordpress featured image url using wordpress timthumb alternative

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I am trying to pass the wp_get_attachment_image_src call through this function

```
<?php 
           $url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );      // Required
$width = 300;                                                                  // Optional. Defaults to '150'
$height = 200;                                                                 // Optional. Defaults to '150'
$crop = true;                                                                  // Optional. Defaults to 'true'
$retina = false;                                                               // Optional. Defaults to 'false'

// Call the resizing function (returns an array)
$image = matthewruddy_image_resize( $url, $width, $height, $crop, $retina );

// Outputs resized image URL, http://yourwordpressdomain.com/wp-content/uploads/01/image1-300x200.png
echo $image['url']; ?>
```

The output does not render the image url but rather

```
<img src=" Array">
```

Please help! I've also tried to create a wordpress function based off of this code , with no luck either:

```
function tuts_custom_img( $thumb_size, $image_width, $image_height ) {

  global $post;

  $params = array( 'width' => $image_width, 'height' => $image_height );

  $url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID, '' ), $thumb_size );
  $custom_img_src = matthewruddy_image_resize( $url[0], $params );

  return $custom_img_src;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

From this `$url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );`

you need to access the image source url as `$url[0]` instead of `$url`.

As here $url is an array.

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
<?php echo $image['url']; ?>
```

you can add this code.

```
<?php echo $url[0]; ?>
```